# With Clang++ is there a way to include a file as namespace, etc.?

Tags: c++, clang++

Is there a way to namespace (or otherwise) the inclusion of a file, without altering the file to be included?
As in something like:

```
#include "A.cpp" as namespace A
```

Whereby, e.g.:

Start.cpp

```
// #include "A.cpp" as namespace A
#include "B.cpp"

int main() {
    // Could call A::Function() 
    // or similar??
}
```

A.cpp

```
int Function() {
    return 1;
}
```

B.cpp

```
int Function() {
    return 2;
}
```

Compilation:

```
clang++ --std=c++2a Start.cpp -o Start.o; ./Start.o
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can wrap the include into a namespace.

```
namespace A {
#include "A.cpp"
}
```

However you have the risk that everything that is included in that file is also part of that new namespace, and that could end up in different issues such as unresolved symbol.

Note: You shouldn't include a cpp file. That's not good.

Answer (score 2):

There is no such feature in C++. Best you can do is:

```
namespace A {
#include "A.cpp"
}
```

`#include` simply pastes the file so this might give you some errors.

Good C++ libraries define their own namespaces.

Hopefully modules in `C++20` will streamline this!